# React - list element text not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm creating a simple **todo app** in **react**. I have three components. The component in charge of displaying the items ('Item' component) is displaying the bullets but not the text. Here's my code,
(edit)

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { list: [] };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(val) {
    let updated = [...this.state.list, val];
    this.setState({ list: updated });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Title itemCount={this.state.list.length}></Title>
        <Add addItem={this.addItem}></Add>
        <Items items={this.state.list}></Items>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Items.js
const Items = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Items">
            <ul>{items.map((item, index) => 
                <li key={index}>
                    {item.text}
                </li>
            )}
            </ul>
        </div>
  );
};
```

edit 2:
Here's an image:
[image]

How can I make it display the text? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiline JSX needs to be wrapped into braces - either format `.map(..` return statement as single line or wrap JSX part into `()`

Comment: did you make sure your items have a `text` field? maybe the problem is in the `Add` component

Comment: I have edited the Items.js part of the code.

Comment: print the list after adding an item so that we can see the list, to print it you can do this, replace setState in addItem to this this.setState({ list: updated }, () => console.log(this.state.list));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that the list doesn't have a text property, so here's the fix:

```
const Items = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Items">
            <ul>{items.map((item, index) => 
                <li key={index}>
                    {item}
                </li>
            )}
            </ul>
        </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
{items.map((item, index) => 
  <li key={index}>
    {item.text}
  </li>
)}
```

the destructed `item` doesn't have a property called `text`, The `item` is carrying your text in this case. So you just need to remove `.text` change your code to this.

```
<li key={index}>
    {item}
</li>
```